# R Plot Multiple Lines According to Choice of User in function()

Tags: r, vector, graph

I want to plot the data by using `function()`. My data consists of 4 vectors, say **a, b, c** and **d**.
I have to plot them by choice of vector at that time.

> For example

- i want to plot vector a and c then graph must have 2 lines....
- if i want 2 plot all 4 vectors then there must be 4 lines in graph.

Till I have tried `switch()` but i think thats not suitable related to my work.
**Is it even possible to write such code in an anonymous function ?**

**If yes, what is the right way, and if not, is there any workaround ?**

Comment: To get a proper answer, you need to supply a lot more detail about what you are trying to achieve.  In the meantime, you might want to look at matplot() for plotting multiple lines.